Python getting value from JSON
I have a response on a request returning this json
Response:  [{"hpsId":10032,"powerPlant":{"name":"Svartisen","id":67302, ....

I get the hpsId by saying
corr_value = response.json()[0]["hpsId"]

But I want the "id" instead, and this is not working ad gives the error "KeyError"
   corr_value = response.json()[0]["id"]

I assume I must say something like this:
corr_value = response.json()[0]["powerPlant.id"]

But not sure how to state it in python code.
Any ideas?

The quick answer is
corr_value = response.json()[0]["powerPlant"]["id"]

But, if there's any possibility that the response data could be missing the powerPlant key, or the 'id' key inside of that value, then you should either wrap that in a try/except block as:
try:
    corr_value = response.json()[0]["powerPlant"]["id"]
except KeyError:
    print("Unable to get powerPlant id")

Or use the .get(key, default) dictionary method instead of directly accessing the key
corr_value = response[0].get("powerPlant",{}).get("id", None)

This will set corr_value to None if either key is missing.

corr_value = response.json()[0]["powerPlant"]["id"]

Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?
